# How to dynamically change the name of FormControls in FormArray

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm dynamically adding rows each with three select menus in my angular project and I need to access the values of them in the component ts file. 
Right now the select menus are named `Col1`, `Comparator`, `Col2`.
When I add another row, the menus in the 2nd row are named the same. That's a problem. How can I change it to a dynamic naming?
Like row 1 has `Col1-a`, `Comparator-a`, `Col2-a` 
row 2 has `Col1-b`, `Comparator-b`, `Col2-b`

component html:

```
<div class="s_form" [formGroup]="form">


    <ng-container formArrayName="block">

        <ng-container *ngFor="let blockForm of block.controls; let j = index">

   
                <div class="block_row" [formGroupName]="j">


        <mat-form-field  [style.width.px]=150 [style.margin-left.px]=10 appearance="fill">
            <mat-select class="select" formControlName="Col1" (click)="getCols()" placeholder="select column 1">
                <mat-option  *ngFor="let i of DfCols" [value]="i" >{{i}}</mat-option>
             </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field  [style.width.px]=100 [style.margin-left.px]=10 appearance="fill">
                <mat-select class="select" formControlName="Comparator" placeholder="comparator">
                    <mat-option  *ngFor="let com of comparator" [value]="com" >{{com}}</mat-option>
                 </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>

                <mat-form-field  [style.width.px]=150 [style.margin-left.px]=10 appearance="fill">
                    <mat-select class="select" formControlName="Col2" (click)="getCols()" placeholder="select column 2">
                        <mat-option  *ngFor="let i of DfCols" [value]="i" >{{i}}</mat-option>
                     </mat-select>
                    </mat-form-field>
                    
               
                    <app-button [style.margin-left.px]=0 class="not_used" color="grey" text="test" (btnClick)="test()"></app-button>
                    <app-button [style.margin-left.px]=0 class="not_used" color="salmon" text="Delete condition block" (btnClick)="deleteblock(j)"></app-button>
                    
    </div>

</ng-container>

</ng-container>
<app-button [style.margin-left.px]=0 class="not_used" color="lightblue" text="Add condition block" (btnClick)="addblock()"></app-button>


</div>
```

component ts:

```
export class FormgroupStrategyComponent implements OnInit {

  DfCols!:any;
  comparator = ['>', '>=', '<', '<=', '==', '!=']


  form = this.fb.group({
      block: this.fb.array([])
  });

  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder, private calculationService: DfCalculationService) { }


  get block() {
    return this.form.controls["block"] as FormArray;
  }

  addblock() {

    const blockForm = this.fb.group({
      Col1: ['', Validators.required],
      Comparator: ['', Validators.required],
      Col2:  ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.block.push(blockForm)
  }

  deleteblock(blockIndex: number) {
    this.block.removeAt(blockIndex);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just keep a counter to give a unique id to each group. You can nest each group inside the main group.

```js
  form = new FormGroup({});

  get groups() {
    return Object.keys(this.form.controls);
  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  deleteblock(blockId: string) {
    this.form.removeControl(blockId);
  }

  counter = 0;
  addblock() {
    const id = this.counter++;
    const blockForm = this.fb.group({
      Col1: ['', Validators.required],
      Comparator: ['', Validators.required],
      Col2: ['', Validators.required],
    });
    this.form.addControl(id.toString(), blockForm);
  }
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div *ngFor="let group of groups" [formGroupName]="group">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select formControlName="Col1"></mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select formControlName="Comparator"> </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select formControlName="Col2"> </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    <button (click)="deleteblock(group)">DELETE</button>
  </div>
  <button (click)="addblock()">ADD</button>
</form>
```

Since each group has their own id, the form controls will have their own namespace. `FormGroup.get()` supports an array of strings to get a control from a nested group

```js
this.form.get(['2', 'Col1']);
```

Comment: ok but how do I deal with that `formControlName="Col1"`in the html component?

Comment: and I get this error: `Error: Cannot find control with path: 'block -> 0 -> Col1-${n}'

Comment: I can't access the id's. `console.log(this.form.get(['0', 'Col1']))` prints `FormControl
defaultValue: null
errors: null
pristine: false
status: "VALID".....`

Comment: I found a simpler way to get the control values, without extra id's. Each `blockForm` has an index anyway inside the array. I can iterate through it and get the individual values: `this.block.value[i]['Col1']`. I think your solution is not complete but it helped me to solve my problem so I accept it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Cool, glad I could help. I opted for the group with keys rather than the array because it makes more sense for deleting - if you delete from the middle of an array you will have an undefined slot or you will have to re-assign all the indices. Whereas having an object with properties acts more like a hashmap.

Comment: That's true, yes. In my project it's ok though because I'll post a json structure to the backend. It will anyway happen that not all keys gonna have values, so if it's undefined I'll leave it empty